# Topic of the Week -- Winter is coming

Tags: discussion

This week it's all about questions pertaining to winter, dealing with winter, not freezing, snow, etc.

Comment: I already posted two questions, should have postponed them maybe :). Oh, and this topic is only valid on the northern hemisphere ;)

Comment: Next week has come! Question time :)

Comment: This one is too broad, and it's been ignored for months.  Break it up into 10 subtopics or so.

Comment: Weekly topics aren't for reply here.  They were themes to suggest questions on the main site.